# Let $G$ be a 5-regular graph with $|V(G)| = 10$. Prove that $G$ has a perfect matching.

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, extremal-graph-theory

I’ve made several attempts at this but can’t quite get there.
We can use the fact that $\nu ~(G) \leq \tau ~(G)$ to bound the matching number of $G$. $|E(G)| = 25$, so if $G$ is 5-regular we require a vertex cover of $|X| = 5$, so we can then say that $\nu ~(G) \leq 5$.
We could potentially also use the fact that for bipartite graphs, $\nu ~(G) = \tau ~(G)$, which proves that if $G$ is bipartite then it has a perfect matching, but then I’m not really sure how to go about addressing the case that $G$ is not bipartite which makes me think this is not the best approach.
Edit: I think it actually makes more sense to approach this using Tutte's theorem, which is that a graph has a perfect matching if and only if for all $X \in V(G)$, the number of connected components with an odd number of vertices in $G - X$ is less than or equal to $|X|$.
For $|X| \in \{5,6,7,8,9\}$, even if every remaining vertex in $G - X$ is an odd component, we would still satisfy that the number of odd components in $G - X$ is  $\leq |X|$, so we need only consider X of the form $|X| \in {1,2,3,4}$
G is 5-regular, therefore it is impossible to have any component of size 1 by deleting less than 5 vertices.
$|X| = 4$: it is impossible for the remaining 6 vertices to form 4 or more components of odd size without any components composed of a single vertex, which we established is impossible for $|X| < 5$. Analogous arguments hold for $|X| = 3$ and $|X| = 2$
For the case that $|X| = 1$ we are guaranteed to be left with 1 odd sized component.

Comment: Your argument looks great to me. Probably needs more details fleshed out for the $|X| < 2$ cases as it seems like it requires some case whacking. When you're free, you can also answer your own question so that it gets removed from the unanswered queue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

And in my opinion it is easier to use Dirac's theorem that
a simple graph with $n$ vertices ($n\geq3$) is Hamiltonian if every vertex has degree
$n/2$ or greater.

Having a Hamiltonian cycle it is easy to construct a perfect matching.

Try it.